# Setting up SVN with development and production server

Tags: svn, version-control

What would be the best practice for a version controlled development and production environment?

I guess my question really is how do you commit the development changes to the production server when ever you want to deploy a feature you've been finalizing in the development environment? Tried to search for the answer without success.

I have used SVN with before, but never set it up myself, so I'm a newbie :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use branching for this kind of purpose. Use one branch (usually trunk for development) and an other branch for production...furthermore you have usually a branch for your current release lets say you are preparing 1.2.0 so you have a branch 1.2.0 in trunk you can do current development....in the branch you can bug fixing only for that particular version....etc. for other releases you can have branches as well..

Comment: The SVN Book has some useful examples of branching best practices: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.html